# Angularjs ui-view routing not working when click on link

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here im using Angular ui-routing function when i click on lick The url is extending in url bar Like [this](http://localhost:63335/Views/Home/Home.html#!/Views/Customer/Customer.html)

ANgularCtrl Is

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router'])
app.config(['$qProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($qProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
    var Custstate = {
        name: 'Customer',
        url: 'Views/Customer/Customer.html',
    }
    $stateProvider.state(Custstate);
}])
```

Ui-view is

```
 <a ui-sref="Customer" ui-sref-active="active">Customer</a>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config register state like this.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('Customer', {
        url: '/Customer',
        templateUrl: 'Views/Customer/Customer.html'
    });

});
```

for more detail see https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router.